# Will java return null value if my java object is storing output as SELECT NVL(COLUMN,0) from

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I am using Select NVL(column1,0) from table_name from the oracle database. The output of the query is stored in Java object.

I need to know if object.getcolumn1value() will return null or 0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try running the code?  Which result did you get then?

Comment: When you `SELECT NVL(column1,0) FROM table_name` then the database will either return the value of `column1` (if column1 is not NULL) or return `0` (if column1 is NULL). Java will therefore never see a NULL value and therefore `object.getcolumn1value()` can never return null.